# Plot a curve to a set of points in python

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I have

```
x_data = [3, 6, 9, 12, 16, 21, 28, 50]
```

and

```
y_data = [0, 333.33333333, 333.33333333, 333.33333333, 250, 200, 142.85714286, 45.45454545]
```

I have attached a graph of what this looks like:

[image: Graph]

I need to fit this to a curve with function: f(x) = a * exp(-x / b) + c.

However I can't get scipy `curve_fit` to work. How can I go about this?

Comment: Do you mean you have to fit *f(x)* to your data?

Comment: You go about this by using scipy `curve_fit`. If it's not working correctly please show what you did and what the problem is.

Comment: However it seems to me that the function you have described isn't the best model for this data. Maybe you meant `a * x * exp(-x/b) + c`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the function you want to fit and then pass it to `curve_fit`. Your function must take the independent variable first and all the remaining parameters after that.

```py
def func(x, a, b, c):
    return a * np.exp(-x / b) + c

# Get parameters and covariance 
params, cov = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(f=f, xdata=x_data, ydata=y_data)

# Declare dedicated letters for each parameter
a, b, c = params

# Plot
plt.plot(x_data, y_data)
plt.plot(x_data, [func(x, a=a, b=b, c=c) for x in x_data])
plt.show()
```

[image]